# Update has_one associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models:

```
Student > belongs_to Locker
Locker  > has_one    Student
```

With this association, i HAVE to go to locker and assign it a student, or if i would turn the association around, i could go to student and assign him a locker.

That is what works and i understand.
But, currently i have it set like described above.

Now, of course, there came up and idea that it would be super cool to directly assign a locker to a student that i am creating (new student).

So in this case, i do have locker, but student is not present at the moment, and when it is created the association from locker to this student should be created, too.
So, effectively a new student with ID XXX would be created, but at the same time this ID should also go to a locker and its student_id attribute.

I am banging my head how to approach this, as i figured out these options don't really do the job (i am using simple_form btw):
- using association
- accepts_nested_attributes

The only way i see it to somehow send fake id (attr_accesor) of selected locker ID to student model, create student, write down its id, find locker, update locker with this new id.

But it feels strange and wrong.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your associations are configured correctly then you have a `:locker_id` in your student table, therefore you can simply have a select box on your new student form.

```
<% form_for @student do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %> # etc...
  <%= form.collection_select(:locker_id, @unassigned_lockers, :id, :name) %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is a really straightforward and standard case unless there is something you aren't telling us.

Note, I have thrown in an `@unassigned_lockers` object instead of doing `Locker.all`, as you would want to have some logic here that only shows unassigned lockers in the dropdown, I assume.

Since you have not set your relationships up the way you originally described you cannot submit a `:locker_id` to a student without manually handling it. As a quick suggestion:

```
<% form_for @student do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %> # etc...
  <%= collection_select_tag(:locker_id, @unassigned_lockers, :id, :name) %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

the select tag will now come through separately in the params, you will need to alter your `create` method to find the locker and update its student id:

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(params[:student])
  if @student.save
    Locker.find(params[:locker_id]).update_attribute(:student, @student)
  end
end
```

This will need some error catching and refinement of course, but should start you off.

Comment: This is exactly a way I took - but I ended with too many IFs and cases. Looks complicated and not effective i think.
Extra comment in new post.

Comment: Meh, can't edit a comment anymore.
We are also not only talking about creating a new student/appending existing locker. But also updating student/locker. This introduces more complexity as there are some combinations to think of. It is just getting more complicated. I was looking into nested_attributes, but came to conclusion it is far from i really want to achieve.

Comment: The code in this answer also would work fine for editing a student... just follow the standard update procedure and include the locker logic after the student save. Make sure you unassign their current locker if `params[:locker_id]` is not equal to the students current locker id.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try your solution, but you did immediately remind of after_create, after_update:

In Student:

```
after_create :update_locker
after_update :update_locker

 private

  def update_locker
    Locker.update(self.locker_id, :student_id => self.id)
  end
```

I do have problem with locker validation now, of course, as only one student can have locker, not more.Currently if i select an already used locker, and update it through my solution, i get successfully updated student message in view, but locker is not updated.